# Definition of a ring S being finitely generated as an R-algebra

Tags: ring-theory, definition

What is the definition of  a ring S being finitely generated as an R-algebra, where R is a ring?

Comment: Could you not have look this up in google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\exists$ onto $R$ algebra homomorphism $S\leftarrow R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.